# "go instead today"

Tags: meaning

> The grown-ups advised me to put away my drawings of boa constrictors,
> outside or inside, and apply myself **instead** to geography; history,
> arithmetic, and grammar.

It's from the Little Prince.

Don't go to the hospital on Monday, **go instead today** (go instead on Thursday).

This is what I made.

Is "go instead today" grammatically and meaningfully correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write "Go today instead".  The normal position of "instead" is at the end.

In the Little Prince, the translator has moved "instead" forward.  This has been done in accordance with the "end weight" principle.  The prepositional phrase "to geography... grammar" is rather long, and long phrases go better at the end of sentences, if grammar allows it.  In contrast "today" is short.

So while "go instead today" is understandable, the normal order of words would be "go today instead".

Comment: Is it only applicable to prepositional phrases? What if adverbs are too long?

Comment: adverbs are single words, so they are not likely to be too long.  Adverb phrases might be too long. So might participle phrases used adverbially.  Try googling "end-weight" to find out more.

Comment: Thank you. By the way if end-weight is applied, should I interpret reversely? e.g. I played soccer twice on my birthday. Can it mean I played soccer on my first birthday and I played soccer on my second birthday, not twice on the same birthday? In the end, should I interpret it in the same way as "I played soccer on my birthday twice"?

Comment: Please ask a new question.  But please please read a text book or a website about "end weight" first!

Comment: @Faints By the way, you ask "is 'go instead today' grammatically and meaningfully correct?" I would say it's not *grammatically incorrect*, and the meaning is certainly clear. It's just not *idiomatic*. I.e. there isn't really a grammar reason for sticking "instead" at the end; it's just "how it's normally done." (Also, practices change over time. The Little Prince was written in 1943, which is already pretty modern, but the tone of this sentence harkens toward an older style, in which it would have been less noteable.)

Comment: @Faints Also, I'm not sure whether it matters that it was originally written in French; I'm not sure what would be idiomatic for the French equivalent and whether that would have influenced the translator.

Comment: @AndyBonner - _Les grandes personnes m'ont conseillé de laisser de côte les dessins de serpents boas ouverts ou fermés, et de m'intéresser plutôt   à la géographie, à  l'histoire, au calcul et à  la grammaire._  Same word order.